# Emptying the object after deserializing a geoJson file in C#

Tags: c#, deserialization, geojson, edit

I have a geoJson file of which this is a part

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872],[45.8830448154499,35.98142063110326],[45.883106013386524,35.98143674855534],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88306057502328,35.98161790966196],[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872]]]},"properties":{"Code":1,"Landuse":"fde","Longitude":45.8830793043,"latitude":35.9815185013}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011],[45.88329577844585,35.981578778123584],[45.883184747057655,35.98160599975271],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88313701140243,35.981503383976175],[45.883107851319025,35.981440699498734],[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011]]]},"properties":{"Code":2,"Landuse":"fde","Longitude":45.8832014571,"latitude":35.9815182472}},
....
```

I want to read this file in C# and edit it based on the property and the code of that property.

I used this view model for deserialization...
`

```
public class Geometry
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
        }

        public class Properties
        {
            public int Code { get; set; }
            public string Landuse { get; set; }
            public double Longitude { get; set; }
            public double latitude { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
            public List<Properties> properties { get; set; }
        }
```

`I use these codes to deserialize and edit the geoJson file...`

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(myPath);
                    var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
                    foreach (var item in deserialize.properties)
                    {
                        if (item.Code == 2)
                        {
                            item.Landuse = ppp;
                        }
                    }
                    string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialize);
                    File.WriteAllText(myPath, output);
                }
```

`
But here the root and deserialize.properties empty are returned?!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have is that the class to which you are trying to deserialize do not correspond with your Json, you can use tools like https://json2csharp.com/ to generate the correct one.

Once you have to correct structures, you should be able to change it without any issue.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I used this exact site to create my classes, and after I uploaded my json file, it gave me these classes, but I encountered the problem that my object is empty during deserialization.I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Root.properties is defined as a List - but in your json it's just a single object.

Changing it to:

```
public class Root
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }

    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
```

solves the problem.

Here's a working example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872],[45.8830448154499,35.98142063110326],[45.883106013386524,35.98143674855534],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88306057502328,35.98161790966196],[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872]]]},\"properties\":{\"Code\":1,\"Landuse\":\"fde\",\"Longitude\":45.8830793043,\"latitude\":35.9815185013}}";

Root result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));

public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Landuse { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }

    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
```

On a side note, I would recommend using System.Text.Json instead.

Comment: I changed the root as you said, but my object is empty when deserialized. However, I want to be query on a list of properties in json file.I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Root.properties isn't empty in the working example above: is your source json different from what you've listed here?  (The json you provide doesn't have a list of "Properties" objects, there is only one...?)

Comment: @mohammad kid, if the answerer's answer doesn't satisfy you, share your input wholly.

Comment: No, the file is the same, and there are hundreds of features inside this file, of which I have placed 2 lines. Each properties of these features has several variables, such as code,Landuse, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on my other answer and the code in your question, I'm guessing that you're trying to filter the feature collection based on the "Code" property.  Try this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\", \"features\": [\r\n{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872],[45.8830448154499,35.98142063110326],[45.883106013386524,35.98143674855534],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88306057502328,35.98161790966196],[45.882982627281955,35.98144306876872]]]},\"properties\":{\"Code\":1,\"Landuse\":\"fde\",\"Longitude\":45.8830793043,\"latitude\":35.9815185013}},\r\n{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011],[45.88329577844585,35.981578778123584],[45.883184747057655,35.98160599975271],[45.883177395327635,35.981590195979166],[45.88313701140243,35.981503383976175],[45.883107851319025,35.981440699498734],[45.88321822952168,35.98143433703011]]]},\"properties\":{\"Code\":2,\"Landuse\":\"fde\",\"Longitude\":45.8832014571,\"latitude\":35.9815182472}} ]}";

FeatureCollection? collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeatureCollection>(json);

if (collection != null)
{
    foreach (var feature in collection.features)
    {
        if (feature.properties.Code == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feature));
        }
    }
}



public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Landuse { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }

    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureCollection
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: return this error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'features[5962].geometry.coordinates[0][0]', line 5964, position 70.'

Comment: Sounds like your data isn't clean.  (and this answer has solved your initial issue)